# AngularJS main controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Currently, I trying to load a page to its home page but i cant make it. Because the first time i load the page its bringing me to app/index.html. Is it possible to redirect the page to app/home?

This is my app.js code:

```
(function () {

"use strict";
//start a new application, a module in Angular
//Application name 
//dependencies are passed through an array
angular.module('MovieApp', ['ngRoute']).config(
    [
        '$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider.
                when('/home', {
                    templateUrl : 'js/partials/home.html',
                }).
                when('/category', {
                    templateUrl : 'js/partials/category-list.html',
                    controller : 'CategoryController'
                }).
                when('/category/:categoryid', {
                    templateUrl : 'js/partials/film-list.html',
                    controller : 'MovieController'
                }).
                when('/actor/:filmid', {
                    templateUrl : 'js/partials/actor-list.html',
                    controller : 'ActorController'
                }).
                when('/movieList', {
                    templateUrl : 'js/partials/allmovie-list.html',
                    controller : 'AllMovieController'
                }).
                when('/search', {
                    templateUrl : 'js/partials/search.html',
                    controller : 'SearchController'
                    // controllerAs: 'movies'
                }).
                when('/login', {
                    templateUrl : 'js/partials/login.html',
                    controller : 'LoginController'
                    // controllerAs: 'movies'
                }).
                when('/logout', {
                    templateUrl : 'js/partials/login.html',
                    controller : 'LogoutController'
                    // controllerAs: 'movies'
                }).
                when('/filmDetails/:filmid', {
                    templateUrl : 'js/partials/note.html',
                    controller : 'FilmDetailController'
                }).
                otherwise({
                    redirectTo : '/'
                });
        } 
    ]
);  // end of config method 
}());   // end of IIFE
```

This is my index.html page:

```
<header>
  <div id="header" data-ng-controller="IndexController">

    <ul>
      <li><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/movieList">Movie List</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/category">Category</a></li>
      <li><a href="#/search">Search</a></li>
      <li ng-hide="loginEnabled"><a href="#/login" >Login</a></li>
      <li ng-hide="logoutEnabled"><a href="#/logout">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
          <h2>{{Message}}</h2>

  </div>
</header>

<div id="content">
  <!-- <h1>Welcome to FMS Website</h1> -->
  <article data-ng-controller="CategoryController"></article></br></br>
  <article data-ng-view></article>
</div>
```

Can someone help me on this. Thank you.

Comment: have u tried to set otherwise to /home?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Did You try this

```
when('/', {
       templateUrl : 'js/partials/home.html',
 })
```

.

Answer (score 0):

change otherwise to your home page,

```
otherwise({
            redirectTo : '/home'
          });
```